# Battery free TPMS

Tags: batteries, wireless, automotive, wireless-charging, wheel

I am doing a report about wireless TPMS, and I heard about products where the sensors in the valves do not need batteries at all (operate and transmit the data). Is that correct?? have you encountered one?
there are all sort of energy harvesters mechanisms that generates power from vibrations or pressure that can probably do the work (piezo-electric, electromagnetic, active RFID, etc.).

I am trying to understand whether TPMS are becoming battery-less, and if so, with which mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that is correct, but if anything in this world has access to a lot of rotational moment, then it's tire pressure sensors. So, a simple coil/magnet combination anywhere in there with some power-harvesting would probably suffice to keep a secondary battery charged.